# How to implement Node-Red Deploy call from a JS event

Tags: node.js, meanjs, node-red

I want to create a custom UI which will only let users wire the flow.Store it. And would deploy the flow only after a specific event is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Node-RED backend there is no distinction between storing and deploying.

If you store the flow in your own code, then you can use the Admin API to deploy it.

http://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/